# Unattended Install for Setup & Deployment project, VS 2005

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, installation

I have a setup & deployment project which includes a large C# project that i have created.
I also have some prerequisites that i bootstrapped to the exe, although the MSI file is, as usual, just the project itself.

I would like to create a **complete unattended install**, not just removing the User interface forms via the UI tab in the Setup project, but to install completely unattended. 
In other words the end user will click on the msi and the installation will run by itself (maybe one form for showing progress...) 
I read quite a bit about the issue but haven't found anything that suits my needs. I read about IExpress but I havent used it, I also read about commands that you can give the msi, but I would have to insert them into the EXE which is a bit of a problem...

Looking for help on the problem.
Thx in advance